# c# DataGridView bound to DataSet format exception

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I've got DataGridView bound to data set:

```
try
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM " + tablename;
    m_adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, m_conn);
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    m_adapter.Fill(DS);
    DBDataGridView.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
    DBDataGridView.Columns[0].Visible = false;
}
```

One of the columns has double type. Comma (',') is used as a double delimiter. When I put dot ('.') instead the exception is thrown:

> The following exception occurred in the DataGridView
>
> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. --->

I tried to implement validation in CellValidating, CellValueChanged events, but still see this exception. I think, that kind of validation should be performed on DataSet level, but don't know how to implement it.
Please advise here

UPDATE: screenshot with error:
[image]

Comment: You need to format the cell, it may help https://forums.asp.net/t/1935349.aspx?Format+to+2+decimal+places+for+a+datacolumn+of+type+double

Comment: Please provide the full exception details, including call stack: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: @BradleyGrainger, added screenshot with the error